# How to change the logging levels in log4j in runtime without restarting jetty server?

Tags: spring, log4j, war, slf4j, jetty-9

Many answers around with option of .setlevel() option,which isn't working in my case because of the below .

**Scenario:**

- log4j.xml file under resources is kept with ERROR mode while jetty startup.

**Code:**

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(test.class);
private static final boolean DEBUG = logger.isDebugEnabled();


if(DEBUG){ //DEBUG will be false as the logging level is set to ERROR
logger.debug("This should print,but it will not print as DEBUG will be set as false during startup"); 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions .

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions:

**1. Correct one**

Change your mode to the desired one. You should not change the logging level at runtime like that. On test platforms, your log level should be `DEBUG`. On production, `INFO`.

**2. Dirty one**

see [Dynamically add appender with slf4j and log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866275/dynamically-add-appender-with-slf4j-and-log4j2). It should be your latest solution.